# Prevent submit without text in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, css

Hi I have a basic one field form with a submit button and it auto clears text onfocus with numbers only allowed. I'm looking to have it disable submit unless numbers are present in the input field and I would like it prevent submit without text in the input field. The problem is the button is a live link. Thanks.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3RZV/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                $("#errmsg").html("Enter Valid Zip!").show().fadeOut("5000");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

#errmsg {
    font:12px normal Futura, sans-serif;
    background:yellow;
    color:#444444;
}
.box {
    width: 85px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.boxtwo {
    width: 160px;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #acd50b;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 11px;
}
input[type="focus"] {
    outline: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #2d8b1b;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #acd50b;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    color: #444444;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
<form action="">
    <div class="box">
        <input type="text" id="quantity" value="Enter Your Zip" /><span id="errmsg"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="boxtwo"> <a href="buttons.html">
             <input type="submit" id="signup" value="Compare"/>
          </a>

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").on( "submit", function(e) {
    if ( !is_valid_zip( $("#quantity").val() ) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
} );
```

Writing the is_valid_zip() function is up to you. You'll probably also want to display an error message to the user, via alert() or similar.

Comment: `if(e.preventDefault) 
     e.preventDefault(); 
else 
   e.returnValue = false;`

Comment: Not necessary - jQuery's event model abstracts away that difference.